# Apache2 mod_rewrite: Basic rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I own two domains, one which I have put up a multisite WordPress site on, and the other which I want to point to one of the multisite's sites, without the user noticing that the url has been changed.

I am rather new to `mod_rewrite`, although I have been testing some configurations without getting them to work, my latest `.htaccess` (that does not work):

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !olddomain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/subsite/$1 [P,L,R=301]
```

I am certain that there's a simple solution to this, but I am just not seeing it at the moment. So any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By not working I mean that it either works with the URL, but the site doesn't work (not loading CSS/JS and/or images). Or the site loads perfectly, but the URL changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding:

```
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.js)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.css)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.woff)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.ttf)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.svg)$ $2 [L]
```

To the main site's `.htaccess`.

Final `.htaccess` on off-site:

```
RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.olddomain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/subsite/$1 [P]
```

Comment: You may simplify that with `RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.(js|css|woff|ttf|svg))$ $2 [L]`

Comment: It is working properly on specific computers, but not all. Mobile phones still redirects instead of rewriting. No idea why it works on my PC but not my phone...